# generating a tree representation for contents of webapp folder

Tags: jsp

All,

We have a ton of JSP includes in our deeply nested webapp folder.It is annoying to digg 5or 6 levals down to find out which JSP is being included where!
is there a easy way to generate a nice tree like structure(on windows) showing the jsp structure?

something like this:

home.jsp
  billing.jsp
    creditcard.jsp

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at backtraces, at least thats what they're called in PHP.

[See Google here](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=jsp+backtrace&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a)